# How to override website fonts in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, fonts

Consider the scenario where a site hardcodes a font name in an HTML document:

```
<font face="Courier">Hello!</font>
```

**Question:** can you configure your system, or an application like Firefox, to use another font instead of the specified ugly font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override any website with your font choices in Firefox.

- Open the Tools->Options menu.
- Select the "Content" tab.
- Click the "Advanced" button in the "Fonts & Colors" section.
- Specify the fonts you would like for each of the types for your encoding.
- Uncheck the check-box labeled "Allow pages to select their own fonts...".

[image]

Comment: You'll get problems on websites which use [web fonts for symbols](https://github.com/blog/1135-the-making-of-octicons) that are in a private unicode range, e.g. all symbols on https://github.com

Answer (score 5):

Do you use linux? For a system-wide font replacement configuration for your user, you can use a ~/.fonts.conf like mine (This is to use the Liberation fonts instead of Time & Arial). See also `man fonts-conf`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>


        <!-- Reject bitmap fonts in favour of Truetype, Postscript, etc. -->
        <selectfont>
                <rejectfont>
                        <pattern>
                                <patelt name="scalable"><bool>false</bool></patelt>
                        </pattern>
                </rejectfont>
        </selectfont>

        <!-- Liberation fonts -->

        <alias>
                <family>Times</family>
                <prefer><family>Liberation Serif</family></prefer>
        </alias>
        <alias>
                <family>Times New Roman</family>
                <prefer><family>Liberation Serif</family></prefer>
        </alias>
        <alias>
                <family>Tahoma</family>
                <prefer><family>Liberation Sans</family></prefer>
        </alias>
        <alias>
                <family>Lucida Grande</family>
                <prefer><family>Liberation Sans</family></prefer>
        </alias>
        <alias>
                <family>Arial</family>
                <prefer><family>Liberation Sans</family></prefer>
        </alias>
        <alias>
                <family>Verdana</family>
                <prefer><family>Liberation Sans</family></prefer>
        </alias>
        <alias>
                <family>Courier</family>
                <prefer><family>Liberation Mono</family></prefer>
        </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108), an add on for Firefox:

> Stylish allows easy management of user
>   styles. User styles empower your
>   browsing experience by letting you fix
>   ugly sites, customize the look of your
>   browser or mail client, or just have
>   fun.

Answer (score 1):

[Create a user stylesheet](http://www.squarefree.com/userstyles/user-style-sheets.html) with a line like:

```
font { font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif !important }
```

This will only affect `font` tags and not any text styled with css - or text that you'd expect to use Courier such as that within `<code>` or `<pre>` tags.

You could also add '`font-size: 100%; color: black`' etc. to further control the text.